# How to define a procedure to call a function in python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.3, anagram, procedures

I have written a function that takes two strings as arguments and returns true or false on whether they have the exact same letters in them. This is my code for it:

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    str1 = sorted(str1)
    str2 = sorted(str2)
    if str1 == str2:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

I now need to define a procedure called test_anagram() that calls the anagram function with different string arguments, using at least three true and false cases. For each case the string and result should be printed out.

I'm not sure about how to achieve this, could anyone help me out?

Comment: First, in Python, a "procedure" and a "function" is the same thing. Some people use the word "procedure" to mean "function that produces side effects and doesn't `return` a value;" some people just use it as a synonym. But either way, you know how to write a function.

Comment: If that's not your actual problem, what part do you not know how to do? How to call `anagram`? How to come up with at least three true and three false cases? How to print out the string and result?

Comment: Your function indentation is incorrect. Indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: Its from copy and pasting it from the python shell.

Comment: @abarnert I didn't know how to put three different cases in the same function!

Comment: I think you should be able to write one line of code to call your function. Where is the problem with copying this line, pasting it 2 times and changing the parameters?

Comment: For the record, I think you have misunderstood the task, because two strings are not anagrams only if they contain the same letters *in the same order*, but rather if they contain they same letters in *any* order. Like "act" and "cat", for instance.

Comment: @dolda2000 i have not misunderstood the task. The code above achieves that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define it like any other function and call the `anagram` function inside `test_anagram` pass strings as arguments:

```
def test_anagram():
    strings = [("foo","bar"),("foo","oof"),("python","jython"),("tear","tare"),("foobar","bar"),("nod","don")] # create pairs of test strings
    for s1,s2 in strings: # ("foo","bar") -> s1 = "foo",s2 = "bar"...
        print(s1,s2) # print each string
        anagram(s1,s2) # call anagram, anagram("foo","bar") ...


In [17]: test_anagram() # call test_anagram()
('foo', 'bar')
False
('foo', 'oof')
True
('python', 'jython')
False
('tear', 'tare')
True
('foobar', 'bar')
False
('nod', 'don')
True
```

Comment: @PadriaicCunningham 

I run that along side my code but it didnt seem to work?
i can get it to print out the strings but not call the anagram function.

Comment: I added the output to my answer, make sure you are calling the function using `test_anagram()` like in my answer